# Subsets of a finite set (different elements)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $(A_1,...,A_n)$ be a family of subsets of a finite set.

How to show:

It exists $n$ different elements $a_1 \in A_1,...,a_n \in A_n \Leftrightarrow |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}^{} A_{i}|\geq |I|$ for all subsets $I\subseteq$ {$1,...,n$}.

I tried to use:

$\Leftarrow:$ Since $|\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}^{} A_{i}|=\sum_{i \in I}^{}{A_i}=A_1 \cup A_2 \cup …\cup A_n \geq |I|$ then there are more elements in the union of all subsets. Also, $I$ has $n$ elements and this is less than the cardinality which implies that they all have to be different.

I'm not sure if this argumentation is correct in this case.

For $\Rightarrow$ I don't see how it could work.

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ is the easy way.  $$|I|=|\{a_i|i\in I\}|\leq\left|\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}^{} A_{i}\right|$$ since $$\{a_i|i\in I\}\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}^{} A_{i}$$ but I don't understand your argument for the converse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\Rightarrow$, 
$$\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}A_i \supseteq \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\},$$
Thus $|\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}A_i| \geq n \geq |I|$ for all $I \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

---

For $\Leftarrow$, you deduction isn't quite right. $|\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{n}A_i| \geq n$ doesn't imply the result. For example, $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{1\},A_3 = \{2,3 \}$ is a counterexample.

Instead, we may use the induction on $n$. For $n=1$, the statement clearly holds. Suppose $n>1$ and the statement holds for $1, \ldots, n-1.$

**Case 1: For all non-empty sets $I \subsetneq \{ 1,\ldots, n\}, |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i| \geq |I| + 1$**

In this case, choose any elements $a_n \in A_n \neq \emptyset$. Then apply the induction hypothesis on $A_1-a_n,\ldots,A_{n-1}-a_n$.

**Case 2: There exist a non-empty set $ I \subsetneq \{ 1,\ldots, n\}$, such that  $|\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i| = |I|$**

WLOG, write $I = \{1,\ldots,k\}$, where $k < n$. Then we first apply induction hypothesis on $A_1, \ldots, A_k$: There exist distinct elements $a_1 \in A_1, \ldots a_k \in A_k$. Let $\tilde{A} = \{a_1,\ldots, a_k\}$. For any $I' \subseteq \{k+1,\ldots, n\},$ we have
$$ |I| + |I'| = |I \cup I'| \leq |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I \cup I'} A_i| \leq |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i| + |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I'} (A_i\backslash\tilde{A})| $$
Hence we get $|I'| \leq |\bigcup\limits_{i \in I'} (A_i\backslash\tilde{A})|$, which shows that we can use the induction hypothesis on $(A_{k+1}\backslash\tilde{A}),\ldots, (A_n\backslash\tilde{A}).$ This completes the proof.

P.S. If you are OK with graph theory, this proposition is equivalent to [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation).